# Extract month names and date numbers from a raw string using regex (Edit: new test cases from 7)

Tags: python, regex

I have a table that has one if its field as a raw string of letters :

1. "get it as soon asdec. 5 - 9 when you choose expedited shipping at checkout."
2. "get it as soon asdec. 10 - 13 when you choose standard shipping at checkout."
3. "get it as soon as"
4. " order soon.   get it as soon asnov. 21 - 26 when you choose standard shipping at checkout."
5. "this item ships to canada. get it by thursday, nov. 21 - monday, dec. 2 choose this date at checkout."
6. "want it friday, nov. 8?order within and choose two-day shipping at checkout."
7. "arrives: july 2 - 3detailsfastest delivery: sunday, june 28details"
8. "arrives: july 6 - 9 fastest delivery: july 1 - 6"
9. "arrives: july 6 - 7detailsfastest delivery: june 30 - july 3"
10. "arrives: july 6 - july 7detailsfastest delivery: june 30 - july 3"

**YES, THERE IS NO SPACE BETWEEN "as" and "dec" IN SOME STRINGS ABOVE**

I want to extract the month names and the dates from these strings and save them into new fields. An example would be:

```
mth_from    mth_to   rng_frm  rng_to    lat_mth  lat_to lat_rn  lat_rng_to
dec          NULL       5        9        NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL
dec          NULL      10       13        NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL
NULL         NULL     NULL      NULL      NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL
nov          NULL      21       26        NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL
nov          dec       21       2         NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL 
nov          NULL       8       NULL      NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL
july         NULL       2       3         june    NULL   28       NULL
july         NULL       6       9         july    NULL    1        6
july         NULL       6       7         june    july    30       3
july         july       6       7         june    july    30       3
```

I tried using regex and created groups

`re.findall("(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec).*?(\d{1,2}).*?(\d{1,2})")`

and (thanks **@wiktor**) **New EDIT**

`(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|june?|july?|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\W*(\d{1,2})(?:\s*-\s*(\d+))?(?:(?:.*?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|june?|july?|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))?\W+(\d{1,2})(?:\s*-\s*(\d+))?)?`

**New Edit End**

It is working well for cases 1, 2, and 4 from above list:

- group 1 = dec
- group 2 = 5
- group 3 = 9 ...

However, it is grabbing full match for `dec. 13 - monday, dec. 23` like:

- group 1 = dec
- group 2 = 13
- group 3 = 23

  instead of creating 4 groups I want when the month name is mentioned again i.e.
- group 1 = dec
- group 2 = 13
- group 3 = dec
- group 4 = 23

Furthermore, it is not extracting anything in case of `want it friday, nov. 8?` which should actually show results like:

- group 1 = nov
- group 2 = 8

Is there a better way to do that runs for all these test cases?

**New EDIT**
Is creating 8 groups ideal? Happy to learn more ideas.

Comment: Your pattern has 3 groups, so you can't expect 4. Try `(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\W*(\d{1,2})(?:.*?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))?\W+(\d{1,2})`, see https://regex101.com/r/aBGPmH/2

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Is there a way to write conditions based on how the strings look? Or create 4 groups as a default and just return NULL if there is no 4th group.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works well for all the cases except for ```want it friday, nov. 8?order within and choose two-day shipping at checkout.``` it does not grab "nov" and "8"

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/aBGPmH/3. You need to wrap Group 3 with an optional group, too.

Comment: You're a genius :). Thank you so much!

Comment: I posted an answer below. Please consider accepting if it worked for you.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew really appreciate your help in this. I recently noticed an addition of new string that looks like `arrives: july 2 - 3detailsfastest delivery: sunday, june 28details` how do I begin capturing 6 groups from now on that would give me `July, 2, NULL, 3, June, 28, NULL, NULL`. It should work for the older strings as well. Let me know if it is not clear

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/shfYsV/1. Also, if my regex works, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, check [https://regex101.com/r/hoRfVh/1]. The last 2 cases seem to not capture all the info. Do you think creating 8 groups would be ideal?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew do you think one regex will cover all the above test cases in https://regex101.com/r/hoRfVh/1. I am struggling since hours :(

Comment: Yes, it does cover them all. However, your requirements are not clear.

Comment: They do cover, however, they are covered in different match for last 2 test cases. Just edited the question and added new test cases from #7. Let me know if it is clear now. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew.

Comment: You can't expect two groups to share the same ID. If `9` is expected in Group 3 in `dec. 5 - 9`, you cannot expect to get `dec` from `nov. 21 - monday, dec. 2` in Group 3.

Comment: Oh no, I meant group 3 can be NULL in the first case. To be more clear, I'd like `Group 1 = month`, `Group 2 = num`, `Group 3=month`, `Group 4=num`, `Group 5=month`, `Group 6=num`,  `Group 7=month`, `Group 8=num` (or any other intuitive way). So for `dec. 5 - 9`, `Group 3` will be `NULL` since it is not mentioned, i.e. it will only have valid `Group 1, 2, 4`. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Just tried https://regex101.com/r/hoRfVh/5. It captures almost everything except for the last 2 test cases-- here, it should add `july` to `group 5` instead of `group 3` and `1` to `group 6` instead of `group 4`. Basically, if the months are after the string "fastest" I am adding them to between groups 5 - 8. Any ideas from this?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hoRfVh/6. But it will make other test cases fail. Sorry, I can't get the requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216982/discussion-between-vineet-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2):

One solution (works with your text input in your question, probably needs more input data to work-out quirks):

```
data = [
    "get it as soon asdec. 5 - 9 when you choose expedited shipping at checkout.",
    "get it as soon asdec. 10 - 13 when you choose standard shipping at checkout.",
    "get it as soon as",
    " order soon. get it as soon asnov. 21 - 26 when you choose standard shipping at checkout.",
    "this item ships to canada. get it by thursday, nov. 21 - monday, dec. 2 choose this date at checkout.",
    "want it friday, nov. 8?order within and choose two-day shipping at checkout.",
]

import re

for line in data:
    m = re.findall(r'((?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\.)|(\d+)', line)
    month_from, month_to, range_from, range_to = 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL'
    if len(m) == 3:
        month_from = m[0][0]
        range_from = m[1][1]
        range_to = m[2][1]
    elif len(m) == 4:
        month_from = m[0][0]
        month_to = m[2][0]
        range_from = m[1][1]
        range_to = m[3][1]
    elif len(m) == 2:
        month_from = m[0][0]
        range_from = m[1][1]

    print('{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(month_from, month_to, range_from, range_to))
```

Prints:

```
dec.       NULL       5          9         
dec.       NULL       10         13        
NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL      
nov.       NULL       21         26        
nov.       dec.       21         2         
nov.       NULL       8          NULL
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Andrej, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use a pattern with a bit more precise patterns in between numbers and a couple of optional groups:

```
(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\W*(\d{1,2})(?:(?:.*?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))?\W+(\d{1,2}))?
```

Or, add word boundaries to only match months as whole words:

```
\b(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\W*(\d{1,2})(?:(?:.*?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))?\W+(\d{1,2}))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aBGPmH/3)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)` - Group 1: abbreviated month names (when they are part of a longer pattern, it makes sense to make each alternative match at a different location in a string, thus, change it to `(j(?:an|u[nl])|feb|ma[ry]|a(?:pr|ug)|sep|oct|nov|dec)`)
- `\W*` - 0 or more non-word chars
- `(\d{1,2})` - Group 2: one or two digits
- `(?:(?:.*?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))?\W+(\d{1,2}))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `(?:.*?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))?` - an optional sequence of

    - `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
    - `(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)` - Group 3: abbreviated month names
  - `\W+` - 1 or more non-word chars
  - `(\d{1,2})` - Group 4: one or two digits

In Python, you may build the pattern dynamically to make it readable:

```
import re
months = r'(j(?:an|u[nl])|feb|ma[ry]|a(?:pr|ug)|sep|oct|nov|dec)'
pat = r'\b{0}\W*(\d{{1,2}})(?:(?:.*?{0})?\W+(\d{{1,2}}))?'.format(months)
re.findall(pat, text)
```