# Extract date and month from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-re

I am trying to extract month and date from a specific type of string.

```
 head_line = 'Weekly Outlook April 1-5: Full NFP buildup and the usual Brexit circus'
```

In this type of strings, Month name contains in the `middle of sentence, after month name date range is specified with - sign`. How can I extract `April 1-5` (month and date) from this string ?

Thanks for your kind attention.

Comment: If you split the string at whitespace - are these always at index 2 and 3? Does the string always start with `Weekly Outlook`? Alternatively - have a look at regex.

Comment: Please, check [ask] and post what have you tried so far.

Comment: No there is random text not always in same position

Comment: I tried using search is string but got stucked. I this using regex or datetime it could be solved easily

Comment: Check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59219456/4046632